# Groovy:General error during semantic analysis: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

Imported the gradle project from the "complete" folder and received the following error:

```
Groovy:General error during semantic analysis:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GeneralUtils.propX(org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression, java.lang.String)'
```

---

I am using the latest version of Eclipse, 2020-12, with groovy tools installed.

From grails guide

- https://guides.grails.org/gorm-without-grails/guide/index.html

Downloaded code sample from github

- https://github.com/grails-guides/gorm-without-grails.git

---

It seems likely to be a version mismatch, but I cannot determine how to correct this problem.

I have tried to delete the offending file, `src/main/groovy/demo/domain/Manufacturer.groovy`, and the error appears on the file in this package on `line 1`.

The error does not appear in any other package. I have done the usual internet searches for resolutions that apply, but have thus far been unable to find a suitable solution.  I am hopeful for a suggestion?

Comment: what are you starting? what error do you have?

Comment: I am not starting or running anything.  The error reported appears as an Eclipse IDE error appears in the Problems view as a Java Problem after importing the project as "Existing Gradle Project".  In Gradle Tasks view, all tasks are visible, but none are available for selection or execution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error comes from an AST transform that references the older signature of `GeneralUtils#propX`. This method used to return `Expression` and was changed to return `PropertyExpression`.

The bridge method for binary compatibility was missing in groovy-eclipse.  https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/commit/f6f448675d95f858b4ec65b6fc8e55f27ccaaa94